# Godot repack fbx file to res (or scn)

Tags: godot, fbx

hi I'm trying to repack fbx file to a readable file for the Godot engine and I gat so far:

```
func fbx_to_scn(node):
var spi = Spatial.new()
add_child(spi)
spi.name = node

node = get_node(node+"/RootNode")

var ps
var mesh
for i in node.get_child_count():
    if node.get_child(i).get_class() == "Skeleton":
        ps = node.get_child(i)
    elif node.get_child(i).get_class() == "MeshInstance":
        mesh = node.get_child(i)

if not ps == null:
    var new_sklet : Skeleton = Skeleton.new()
    for i in ps.get_bone_count():
        new_sklet.add_bone(ps.get_bone_name(i))
        new_sklet.set_bone_rest(i,ps.get_bone_rest(i))
        if ps.get_bone_parent(i) == -1:
            continue
        new_sklet.set_bone_parent(i,ps.get_bone_parent(i))
    spi.add_child(new_sklet)
    new_sklet.owner = spi
    new_sklet.name = "Skeleton"

var mi = MeshInstance.new()
mi.name = "MeshInstance"
mi.mesh = mesh.mesh
spi.add_child(mi)
mi.owner = spi
if not ps == null:
    mi.skeleton = "../Skeleton"

var pack = PackedScene.new()
pack.pack(spi)

if ResourceSaver.save("res://save_file/" +spi.name+ ".scn",pack) == OK:
    print("file saved")
else:
    print("some thing went wrong")
```

everything goes well and the file is created like this

[image]

but the rig is so bad

[image]

the left shape is the fbx file and the right is scn file
the rig is completely reverse and it's not even the same (had some changes)

Comment: Any reason why you are not packing the node directly? Edit: if packing the node directly does not work for you, you can use `duplicate` on the nodes to create copies.

Comment: I totally forgot to use duplicate and test that method and work very good (if repack rigged file) but my purpose is to create a new rig for the file that is not rigged (and do some changes in the rig ) so a test this method and the same problem popup its rigged but in the wrong way